# Oracle - Connect By Clause Required in query block

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to utilize the Month Column in the below syntax in a Case Statement. When I create a sub query I receive the Oracle error 01788 Connect By Clause Required in query block. How can one utilize the Month column in the case statment in the subquery?

```
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(StartDate, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1), 'YYYYMM') AS Month
```

Query below:

```
    SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN  first_assgn_dt_YYYYMM <= Month 
   THEN 0
  WHEN EndDate < LAST_DAY(EndDate) AND EndDate != sysdate 
 AND LEVEL = 1 + MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(EndDate,'MM'),TRUNC(StartDate,'MM'))
  THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 
      END AS active_at_month_end 

        FROM (
WITH
     ActiveMemberData (ID,StartDate,EndDate,first_assgn_dt,first_assgn_dt_YYYYMM) AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT 
       x.ID,
       TRUNC(x.start_dt) AS StartDate,
       CASE WHEN TRUNC(X.END_DT) = '1-JAN-3000' THEN SYSDATE ELSE TO_DATE(X.END_DT) END AS EndDate,
       x.first_assgn_dt,
       TO_CHAR(first_assgn_dt,'YYYYMM') AS first_assgn_dt_YYYYMM

FROM X
LEFT JOIN  D ON X.MID = D.ID  

WHERE 1=1

                               )                                   
--------------------------------------------------                                       
   SELECT DISTINCT 
ID,
first_assgn_dt,
first_assgn_dt_YYYYMM,
StartDate,
TO_CHAR(StartDate,'YYYYMM') AS StartDate_YYYYMM, 
EndDate,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(StartDate, 'MM'), LEVEL - 1), 'YYYYMM') AS Month,
LAST_DAY(EndDate) AS LastDayOfMonth

FROM  ActiveMemberData

WHERE 1=1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(EndDate,'MM'), TRUNC(StartDate,'MM'))
  AND PRIOR ID = ID AND PRIOR STARTDATE = STARTDATE
  AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL          
                       ) Z
WHERE 1=1

ORDER BY
ID, 
Month
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has nothing to do with trying to refer to `Month` from the inline view; that is fine. It's the separate reference to `level` that is causing the error.

If you want to be able to see the `level` from your inline view in the outer query, as you are with this line:

```
 AND LEVEL = 1 + MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(EndDate,'MM'),TRUNC(StartDate,'MM'))
```

then you have to include it in the select list - with an alias - and then refer to that alias:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
...
 AND LEVEL_ALIAS = 1 + MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(EndDate,'MM'),TRUNC(StartDate,'MM'))
...
FROM (
...
   SELECT DISTINCT 
     LEVEL as LEVEL_ALIAS,
     ID,
...
```

You can call the alias whatever you want, of course; you just can't use the reserved word `level`.

Anything you want visible in the outer query always has to be in the inline view's select list - but usually you can keep the original column name; you have to use an alias for an expression or a pseucocolumn though, which is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use an alias for the reserved word. Just add double quotes and capitilise it i.e. "LEVEL"